# How to set up an autoupdated blacklist for Dansguardian?

Tags: dansguardian

I'm having issues setting up Dansguardian on my computer with Ubuntu 13.10. I'm trying to follow the steps in the Ubuntu Community Documentation for Dansguardian: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DansGuardian

I installed the programs it specified via terminal command with no errors. Then I downloaded the blacklists from http://urlblacklist.com/?sec=download and extracted the files.

The next step is to run:

```
tar -xzf bigblacklist.tar.gz
```

I tried running that command, but get this response:

```
john-hill@johnhill-desktop:~$ tar -xzf bigblacklist.tar.gz
tar (child): bigblacklist.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
john-hill@johnhill-desktop:~$
```

Any ideas? Or is there a better way to set up the blacklists? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you already extracted the files, you do not need to manually extract them again with that tar command.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below commands on terminal,

```
cd /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/bigblacklist.tar.gz
tar -xzf bigblacklist.tar.gz
```

Comment: I get this response when running those commands: john-hill@johnhill-desktop:~$ cd /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/bigblacklist.tar.gz
bash: cd: /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/bigblacklist.tar.gz: No such file or directory
john-hill@johnhill-desktop:~$ tar -xzf bigblacklist.tar.gz
tar (child): bigblacklist.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
john-hill@johnhill-desktop:~$

Comment: no, where you download the bigblacklist.tar.gz file(in which folder did you download the bigblacklist.tar.gz file)?

Comment: It's in my downloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you better off executing this script:

```
curl -L http://urlblacklist.com/downloads/UpdateBL | sudo sh
```